# Google Apps Script - flat project clasp structure

Tags: google-apps-script, clasp

I'm trying to start editing Google Apps scripts that are bounded to Google Sheets.

I don't understand the part where it is documented that

```
Structure Code. clasp automatically converts your flat project on script.google.com into folders. For example:
```

## On script.google.com:

├── tests/slides.gs

└── tests/sheets.gs

## Locally:

├── tests/

│   ├─ slides.gs

│   └─ sheets.gs

When I see my projects on script.google.com they are just listed by the name, I don't see any folder structure.

I was able to to a clasp clone PROJECT_ID and it downloaded 3 files

Cloned 3 files.

└─ appsscript.json

└─ Code.js

└─ Old Code.js

exactly to the folder where I ran the clasp command.

I don't see how it creates folders for me..

Should I be creating one folder per script?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On script.google.com, the files will **always** be in a flat structure. What clasp does is--if there is a filepath separator in the .gs filename--nests that into a folder in your local Dev environment.

So if your gs files are "a.gs" and "old b.gs", they will be in the same directory when you `clasp pull`. If they are named ”a.gs" and "old/b.gs", when you `clasp pull`, the current directory will contain a js file named "a.js" and a directory named "old", which contains a file named "b.js".

Similarly, if you create a directory-based project locally and then push it to Apps Script, clasp will flatten suitable files in your local directory so Apps Script can use them.

I.e.

```
webapp/
 - a.js
 - b.js
main.js
```

Will become

```
webapp/a.gs
webapp/b.gs
main.gs
```

after pushing.

PS: shared development may be tricky in multi-OS teams while this bug is open: https://github.com/google/clasp/issues/393

Comment: Yes, that's the explanation I was expecting. Kind of confirms what I thought but didn't find nowhere explained like this, so kudos. And also thanks for heads up on the shared development. On this case I just want to have an "offline" backup.

Answer (score 1):

Google Script editor doesn't support folders, all files are always uploaded into the root.